# How can I open the metamask mobile application from my web-app?

Tags: vue.js, mobile, vite, metamask

I am trying to connect a web app to the metamask wallet. I am able to do that with the extension on the browser. But I could not open the metamask mobile application on my mobile device.

My attempt so far:

```
<script>
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider'

export default {
  name: 'metaProvider',
  data() {},
  methods: {
    async checkMetamask() {
      const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()
      if (provider) {
        console.log('Metamask detected!')
        const accounts = await provider.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
        console.log(accounts)
      } else {
        console.log('Metamask not detected')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style></style>
<template>
  <button @click="checkMetamask">connect to meta mask alone</button>
</template>
```

What do I need to open the metamask mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work on mobile since mobile browsers don't get injected with the provider, I suggest using walletconnect, it open's up a qr code on browsers that don't get injected and allows you to scan with any wallet provider!